# Divide Array to 2 sub arrays and check if the multiplication are equal

Tags: java, recursion, sqrt

I practice for an exam in Java.
One of the questions I faced today is:
Given an array with n numbers, I need to check if there are 2 subarrays(doesn't have to be equal) that their multiplication equals - if there are, will return true, else false.
for example :
if the array is : {2,15,3,4,2,5} - will return True
if the array is : {2,4,6,2,3,4} - will return False.

the answer must be recursive, without any loops.

so I thought that if there are 2 sub arrays that their multiplication equal it means that the total multiplication of the whole array must be a square root number. for example at the first array, it's 3600 which is 60.

So far I couldn't find any case that it won't work for, but still not sure 100% that it will cover all the possible cases.

This is my code for that:

```
    public static boolean splitEqualMult(int[] a) {
      double multi = isArrSqrt(a,0);

      if(Math.sqrt(multi) == Math.floor(Math.sqrt(multi))) {
          return true;
    }

    return false;
}

private static double isArrSqrt(int[] a, int i) {

    if(i == a.length) {
        return 1;
    }

    return a[i] * isArrSqrt(a,i+1);
}
```

looking to hear your thoughts!

Comment: Test your code for input of `{2,8}`. Does it succeed? Should it?

Comment: Why the second return false? Does not 2*6=4*3?

Comment: @TiMr My interpretation is that all numbers must be used.

Comment: @Joakim Danielson Should we respect the order? I.e the substring is not collected from different parts of the original, as you understand it.

Comment: will you illustrate , 1st and 2nd example in detail ???

Comment: @TiMr, no substring here only numbers. And as I see it the numbers can be collected from different parts like 15 * 4 = 2 * 2* 3 * 5

Comment: @Joakim I see, thank you.

Comment: @nullpointer He should also test {2,8,1,1,1...} , {4,9,1...}, {3,4,3,1..} it will aprove them and it is wrong!!

Answer (score 4):

Your solution gives false positives. For example, the array `{2,8}` cannot be divided into two sub-arrays of equal product, but you'll return `true`, since the square root of 2*8 is 4.

When you try to solve such a recursion you should try to think what happens if you reduce the size of the input by 1.

Suppose a given array `arr` has a valid split (into two sub-groups having equal product). This means that if you remove the first element `a[0]`, you must be able to split the rest of the array into two sub-groups such that `p1 == p2 * a[0]` or `p1 == p2 / a[0]`, where `p1` is the product of the elements of the first group and `p2` is the product of the elements of the second group.

This suggests that the recursive method should check whether for a given tail of the input array (i.e. arr[from]...arr[arr.length-1] for some from >= 0), there exists a split into two groups such that the product of the first group divided by the product of the second group (or vice versa) equals a given factor:

```
public static boolean canSplit(int[] arr, int from, double factor)
{
    if (from == arr.length - 1) {
        return arr[from] == factor;
    }
    return canSplit(arr, from + 1, factor * arr[from]) || canSplit(arr, from + 1, factor / arr[from]);
}
```

The initial call will be:

```
public static boolean canSplit(int[] arr)
{
    if (arr.length < 2) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return canSplit(arr, 0, 1); // the second parameter is 0, since the first recursive call
                                    // applies to the whole array
                                    // the third parameter is 1, since we want to check if there 
                                    // are two groups such that the product of the first divided
                                    // by the product of the second is 1 (i.e. the two products
                                    // are equal)
    }
}
```

Tests:

```
System.out.println (canSplit(new int[]{2,15,3,4,2,5}));
System.out.println (canSplit(new int[]{2,4,6,2,3,4}));
System.out.println (canSplit(new int[]{2,2,4}));
System.out.println (canSplit(new int[]{2,8}));
```

Output:

```
true
false
true
false
```

Comment: An edge case is of course if 0 can be used or not, one 0 => always false, more than one 0 => always true. Anyway, I up voted this very well explained answer.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yes, it wasn't clear whether or not the input can contain 0s or not, and my solution will fail if 0s are present.

Comment: Yep, thanks - thought I might found something easier but your code is much more practical and easy to write compare to my brute force code.

Comment: @TiMr thanks, I was too tired when I posted this. I believe it is correct now.

Answer (score 0):

I used a different strategy for this question

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println(splitEqualMult(new int[] { 2, 15, 3, 4, 2, 5 })); // true
    System.out.println(splitEqualMult(new int[] { 2, 4, 6, 2, 3, 4 })); // false
    System.out.println(splitEqualMult(new int[] { 2, 2, 4 })); // true
    System.out.println(splitEqualMult(new int[] { 2, 8 })); // false
}

public static boolean splitEqualMult(int[] a)
{
    return splitEqualMult(a, 1, 1, 0);
}

private static boolean splitEqualMult(int[] a, int multGroupA, int multGroupB, int i)
{
    if (i == a.length)
        return multGroupA == multGroupB; // upon completion we need to check if the groups are equal

    return splitEqualMult(a, multGroupA * a[i], multGroupB, i + 1) // try add the product to groupA
            || splitEqualMult(a, multGroupA, multGroupB * a[i], i + 1); // try add the product to groupB
}
```

Output:

```
true
false
true
false
```