# Check recursively if possible to split an array into two arrays meeting certain criteria

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, recursion

I'm tackling the following problem from [CodingBat](https://codingbat.com/prob/p171660):

> Given an array of ints, is it possible to divide the ints into two groups, so that the sum of one group is a multiple of 10, and the sum of the other group is odd. Every int must be in one group or the other. Write a recursive helper method that takes whatever arguments you like, and make the initial call to your recursive helper from splitOdd10(). (No loops needed.)

I found [a post on SO discussing a similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53898486/divide-array-to-2-sub-arrays-and-check-if-the-multiplication-are-equal) of whether it's possible to split an array into two having equal product, and tried writing the code by analogy. This is what I got so far (in Java):

```
public boolean splitOdd10(int[] nums) {
    if (nums.length == 0)
    return false;
  else
    return canSplit(0, nums, 0);
}

private boolean canSplit(int first, int[] nums, int term) {
    if (first == nums.length - 1)
    return (term + nums[first]) % 10 == 0 || (term + nums[first]) % 2 == 1;
  else
    return canSplit(first + 1, nums, term + nums[first]);
}
```

But upon pondering the code further, I understand that it merely checks whether the sum of the original array as a whole is either a multiple of 10 or odd.

I'm having a hard time trying to understand how to step from n to n-1 and what the binding condition should be as the two arrays are not dependent on each other, unlike when their products are equal.

Can someone please give me a hint? Thanks.

Comment: Not very sure if this was clarified in the problem. But could either of a group be empty? e.g. `nums` size `1` or if all elements can satisfy one condition group them into one group?

Comment: @nullpointer I just looked up - the expected answer for {1} is true, so yes, one of the arrays may be empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have to make two groups (A and B). For each element, you have two choices: either you can put the current element into group A or to group B.

States: mod10 (sum of all elements in group A module 10), odd2 (sum of all elements in group B module 2)

```
bool check(int arr[], int idx, int mod10, int odd2,  int size){ 

  if(idx == size){

     return (mod10 == 0 and odd2 == 1);
}

   // include current element in group A

  bool first_choice = check(arr, idx + 1, (mod10 + arr[idx]) % 10, odd2, size)

   // include  current element in group B

  bool second_choice = check(arr, idx + 1, mod10, (odd2 + arr[idx]) % 2, size)

  return (first_choice or second_choice);    
}
```

You can save these states in the table , Complexity O( size * 10 * 2 ) where size = total elements in the array

Comment: why do you need to pass the mods into the function?

Answer (score 0):

Will just post my own code, which I believe is a little clearer (at least to me):

```
public boolean splitOdd10(int[] nums) {     
  if (nums.length == 0)
    return false;
  else
    return canSplit(0, nums, 0, 0);
}

private boolean canSplit(int index, int[] nums, int mod10Sum, int oddSum) {

  if (index == nums.length)
    return mod10Sum % 10 == 0 && oddSum % 2 == 1;
  else
    return canSplit(index + 1, nums, mod10Sum + nums[index], oddSum)
          || canSplit(index + 1, nums, mod10Sum, oddSum + nums[index]);
}
```